# Publish Local generates empty jar in a multi-module SBT project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

When I do publishLocal on some modules it works, but for one module it generates empty jar with only `META-INF/Manifest.MF` . All modules have a standard folder structure `src>main>scala` . The only difference is this module has no main class and is just a module with a lot of util classes used by other modules.

More details below:

I have a standard folder structure for a multi project build.

```
├── project
│   └── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
├── build.sbt
├── Bar
│   └── src
├── Fizz
│   └── src
└── Foo
    └── src
```

My plugins.sbt is : `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")`

My build.sbt is

```
ThisBuild / name := "My main Project"

ThisBuild / version := "0.1"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

//Modules/Projects
lazy val global = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(settings)
  .disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
  .aggregate(
    bar,
    fizz,
    foo
  )

lazy val bar = project
  .settings(
    name := "Bar",
    settings,
    assemblySettings
  )

lazy val fizz = project
  .settings(
    name := "Fizz",
    settings,
    assemblySettings
  )

lazy val foo = project
  .settings(
    name := "Foo",
    settings,
    assemblySettings
  )
  .dependsOn(
    fizz
  )

lazy val compilerOptions = Seq(
  "-encoding",
  "utf8"
)

lazy val settings = Seq(
  scalacOptions ++= compilerOptions
)

lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
  }
)
```

So `bar/publishLocal` works but `fizz/publishLocal` generates an empty jar, and then any other project relaying on published local jar of fizz fails.

Edit: Fixed typo of Fuzz to Fizz

Comment: `Fuzz` or `fizz`? If you try to publish fuzz but defined fizz, that could explain..

Comment: @GaëlJ fixed, that was a typo, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the above issue was only an issue in jenkins and not anywhere else. Fixed that by renaming the variables in `build.sbt` to PascalCase to match the folder names and then correct jars were created. For e.g.

```
lazy val Foo = project
  .settings(
    name := "Foo",
    settings,
    assemblySettings
  )
  .dependsOn(
    Fizz
  )
```